# How to know the div element loaded completely angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

We are working on angularjs and html application. My requirement is to know the complete loading of a div, i.e. want to know complete rendering of all the elements of a div.

Lets say div A contains all the elements. In which some elements are loaded and created on run time, after all pre-created HTML elements are loaded.

Sample div is :

```
<div id="myMainDiv" class="tab-pane fade" >    
    <div class="col-sm-4"><input id="myEle1" type="text" class="form-control"
    maxlength="250" tab-group="g1" tab-index="0" tab-man ng-model="vm.min"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"><span style="font-size: 25px;"><a href="" id="myEle2" tooltip-placement='right'
    uib-tooltip-template="'tooltipContent.html'"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" style="color:#061530;"></i></a></span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12" ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.myRunTimeList">
        <div class="col-sm-5">{{::key}}</div>
        <div class="col-sm-7" style="display:flex;">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                   style="width:60%;margin-right: 5px;" readonly
                   ng-model="value.retCode"/>
            <span style="font-size: 25px;">
                <a href="" id="desc{{$index}}" tooltip-placement='top-right'
                uib-tooltip="{{value.retDescription}}"><i
                class="fa fa-info-circle" style="color:#061530;"></i></a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this vm.myRunTimeList is creating element after rendering pre elements.
My div is complete after loading all elements whether pre created and run time elements.

How can I achieve all loading of elements in a div?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, probably postLink? In general there is no 'finish render', cause render may be async, so it may never finish.

Answer (score 0):

Just add onload = myfunction() to `<div id="myMainDiv" class="tab-pane fade" >`.

giving  `<div id="myMainDiv" class="tab-pane fade" onload = myfunction()>`.

Then your js function will be called when load is complete, and you can note the fact.

Comment: Thanks! but this option I have tried and this not working.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're wanting to run a function after the initial digest cycle?  Use the timeout service

Inject $timeout into your controller and then use.  This will wait till after digest cycle is complete.  If you're loading API data or something you may need to put it inside the resolve of that promise.

```
$timeout(function() {
   //whatever you want to happen after render
}, 0);
```

The zero argument is actually optional, I usually keep it, but your preference.